# Powershell script executed by an C# assembly doesn't work (Cannot convert value)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-assembly

I have a simple console application, written in `C#` which invokes a `PowerShell` script. Everything works until I add an additional assembly to the console application which is **also loaded within the PowerShell script**.

Here is the invoke of the `PowerShell` script:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);           
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command command = new Command(@"d:\invokeme.ps1");

pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

pipeline.Invoke();
```

The PowerShell script loads two assemblies:

**AssemblyA:**

```
namespace AssemblyA
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public readonly string Name;

        public ClassA(string aName)
        {
            Name = aName;
        }
    }
}
```

**AssemblyB:**

```
namespace AssemblyB
{
    public class ClassB
    {
        private readonly ClassA classA;

        public ClassB(ClassA aClassA)
        {
            classA = aClassA;
        }

        public string GetText()
        {
            return classA.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the PowerShell script:

```
$assemblyA = "D:\Projects\PsInvoke\AssemblyA\bin\Debug\AssemblyA.dll"
$assemblyB = "D:\Projects\PsInvoke\AssemblyB\bin\Debug\AssemblyB.dll"

Add-Type -Path $assemblyA
Add-Type -Path $assemblyB

$objA = New-Object -TypeName AssemblyA.ClassA 'Hello'
$objB = New-Object -TypeName AssemblyB.ClassB $objA
```

The console application works **until** I add and use a reference of AssemblyA to the console application, then I receive the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException' occurred in
>   System.Management.Automation.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot convert argument "0", with value:
>   "AssemblyA.ClassA", for "ClassB" to type "AssemblyA.ClassA": "**Cannot
>   convert the "AssemblyA.ClassA" value of type "AssemblyA.ClassA" to
>   type "AssemblyA.ClassA**"."

If I **also add** and use a **refernce to AssemblyB** to the console application, everything **works** fine!

Is there a different workaround than loading each assembly used in the `PowerShell` script in both - the `PowerShell` script and the console application? Can someone explain that behaviour?

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, `AssemblyB` has a reference to `AssemblyA`, or is it the other way?

Comment: Yes, AssemblyB has a reference to AssemblyA, but not the other way

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it, but I think the problem lies in that the powershell runspace is in the same AppDomain as the hosting program. You've now added a library to the AppDomain twice. Try removing the `Add-Type` for the library that the application references?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still receive the same error when I remove the Add-Type within my PowerShell Script.